# Call notification toast from component class

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am learning angular html with typescript. I am following a tutorial (e-commerce website) and trying to add `toast` feature. This is how my component class is implemented

```
export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit {

   showToast:boolean=false;
   notification_message:string='';
   constructor(private toastService:ToastService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
   this.toastService.getToastMsg().subscribe((productName:string)=>{
     this.showToast=true; // this line is always called 
     this.notification_message=productName+' was added';
   })
 }
}
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="notification-toast">
<ngb-toast
    *ngIf="showToast"
    header="Notification"
    [autohide]="true"
    [delay]="2000">
    {{notification_message}}
  </ngb-toast>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.notification-toast {
    opacity:1;
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

However when I click `addtocart` button the toast get's displayed only once. Please let me know if you want to see any other code too.

Comment: would be useful to see the code of the `addtocart` click handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what toast service you are using, but considering the prefix of the tag ngb, I'm thinking it's the `ngb-toast` package.

In that case you need to call the `show` method on `toastService`, with a `NgbToast` message as a parameter.

From the code it looks like you tried to implement your own toast component, or something similar.

Some snippets from the ngb-toast page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngb-toast), adapted to your context:

Step 1
Add tag in your app.component.html file

```
<ngb-toast-container></ngb-toast-container>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Step 2
Import NgbToastService into your component.ts file

```
@Component({...})
export  class  YourComponent  {
    constructor(private  toastService:  NgbToastService) {}
    ...
    showProductWasAddedMessage (productName): void {
        const toast: NgbToast = {
            toastType:  NgbToastType.Success,
            text:  productName+' was added',
            dismissible:  true,
            onDismiss: () => {
                console.log("Toast dismissed!!");
            }
        }
        this.toastService.show(toast);
    }   
}
```

showProductWasAddedMessage should be called as a click handler or after some other operations.